# how to install package for visualation msgs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "visualisation_msgs" with any of the following names:

    visualisation_msgsConfig.cmake
    visualisation_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "visualisation_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "visualisation_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "visualisation_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  using_markers/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225970/how-to-install-package-for-visualation-msgs/) by [harshit](https://answers.ros.org/users/25864/harshit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

they are in the common_msgs package

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0